# Check if project exist on disk

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I can check if a project exists on the Eclipse workspace with:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().exists(IPath path)
```

However this does not check if the project was "soft" deleted before and already exists on disk.

How do I check if the project already exists on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the workspace location to get a normal Java `File` object:

```java
IPath workspacePath = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation();

IPath fullPath = workspacePath.append(relative path);

File file = fullPath.toFile();
```